# Hortonworks HDP How to set up a Kerberos enabled Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox, keytab

I have recently downloaded Hortonworks HDP VM. I am able to run Kafka on it. I can produce/consume messages through ***security-protocol=PLAINTEXT***.

However, I now want to consume through ***security-protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT*** and Kerberos.

I know that I can setup, `SASL_PLAINTEXT` through Ambari (Screenshot attached) but I would like to know if there is a consolidated guide or article on this which would let me know of the following?

- How to setup Kerberos on HDP Sandbox VM
- How to setup keytabs in HDP Sandbox VM
- How to setup Kafka to run with SASL_PLAINTEXT in HDP Sandbox VM
- How to consume/produce through security-protocl=SASL_PLAINTEXT

My HDP Sandbox version details are:

```
== Sandbox Information ==
Platform: hdp-security
Build date: 06-18-2018
Ambari version: 2.6.2.0-155
Hadoop version: Hadoop 2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292
OS: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
====
```

Screenshot for KAFKA `SASL_PLAINTEXT` setup through AMBARI is given below:

[image: KAFKA SASL_PLAINTEXT setup through AMBARI]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what issues you are having after trying this configuration. Asking for tutorials is considered off-topic fof StackOverflow. Perhaps you can have better luck on Hortonworks forums

Comment: In any case, start at the HDP documentation - https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_security/content/configuring_amb_hdp_for_kerberos.html and follow the guides on the left down from there where you can find Kafka setup

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install Kerberos
You can follow the instrucion
https://github.com/dmilan77/Kerberos/blob/master/Kerbersos_install.md
Once Installed you can use HDP Kerberos wizart to install it.